# Why can't I install xubuntu-desktop?

Tags: xubuntu

When I try to install Xubuntu on my current Ubuntu installation, it won't let me install "xubuntu-desktop", but it will instead recommend me to install other packages in the Xubuntu repos.

Has the package name changed or do I have to wait for an updated version?

Comment: `UPDATE:` I figured it out. I installed an unstable repo for GIMP and I had to force install it in order to get the package list working again. Problem solved. Installing `xubuntu-desktop` now.

Comment: You could put what you did to fix it as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

The `xubuntu-desktop` is a **meta-package**. That means, that it's a package that serves as a single point linking to other packages. Something like a pointer to many other different packages.

Hence `xubuntu-desktop` package's only contents are links to other xfce related packages, the packages that make up the Xubuntu Desktop.

You could also read the [Ubuntu Community Documentation on MetaPackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages)

Comment: But I installed the xubuntu-desktop with the command: `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`. Explain that!

Comment: Same, I was able to do `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` before, but now I'm starting to think my package manager is broken.

Comment: @Alvar: Yup that is the command to install `xubuntu-desktop` which in turn installs all the other required packages to make your xfce DE. @Robert:Tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` ?